# SQL Server : using unique identifier in Where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, uniqueidentifier

I ran this query:

```
select
    *
from
    [dbo].[planservice]
where
    cast([serviceid] as varchar(255)) = cast('49D9161A-B92B-E911-8101-001056B242CB' as varchar(255))
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error message:

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to a uniqueidentifier

Wouldn't they both be considered strings?

**Edit**: this does work without the casting, the reason my query did not work is because I had this part before included in my where clause:

```
a.[planid] = ''
```

Once I removed that, everything worked fine. The question is, why is that a problem?

Edit: I am not sure why people are marking this to be closed. It works, but I have no idea why it works.

Comment: Please post your table definition.

Comment: Why would I delete my question? It works but I don't understand why it works when I remove a particular section in my where clause?

Comment: Because a blank string is not a valid unique identifier. You probably want `a.[planid] is null`

Comment: Perhaps because you have no rows where planid equals nothing... perhaps you meant `IS NULL`

Comment: No. Null values and empty strings are two different things.

Comment: Nope, some of the records have empty strings. Long story.

Comment: For that to be giving an error `planid` must be a uniqueidentifier in your table definition, in which case it cannot be an empty string.

Comment: I'll play around with it.

Comment: The problem with the question is that is isn't clear, doesn't provide enough information and has contradictions. So you have whole bunch of frustrated people, you not getting the answer you want, and the people who want to assist not getting the information they want. You need to post enough code for us to be able to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `serviceid` is `uniqueidentifier` then why are you casting it to `varchar(255)`? You can simply run

```
select
*
from
[dbo].[planservice]
where [serviceid] = '49D9161A-B92B-E911-8101-001056B242CB'
```

This will work fine for `uniqueidentifier`.

Comment: That did not work for me, I tried that initially. Ah wait, I figured out why it didn't work. Interesting.

Comment: @LunchBox if that didn't work, then you have another problem somewhere.

Comment: I edited my original query to show what I was doing originally.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer. I don't understand the downvotes; however, I have lost interest and would rather just close the question now. I'll play around and see if I can figure it out later.